# How to warp text like it's in a tube?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I am looking for ways to warp text so that it looks like it inside of a tube. Here is a piece by Felix Pfaeffli that is similar to what I want to accomplish.

[image: http://www.feixen.ch/wp-content/uploads/Holy_Other_2.jpg]

Comment: I have tried the Envelope Distort, Warp feature but can't get the text to appear like it's wrapping around and object. Really, I'm wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish something like this other than hand rendering it with the pen tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use Illustrator's 3D effect for a base.

Draw a series of rectangles.....

[image]

Select them all and drag them to the **Symbols Panel**

Then draw a circle, just a standard circle, and choose `Effect > 3D > Extrude and Rotate`. (I filled my circle with yellow so it can be seen.)

[image]

Click the **Map Art** button, navigate to the correct side, and then pick your symbol of rectangles. Then click **Scale to fit** and check the **Invisible Geometry** option. . .

[image]

Click `OK` twice to apply the effect.

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu, then choose `Object > Expand`. You may need to also `Object > Ungroup`.

Ultimately this gives you a series of consistently placed curves which can then be altered with different fills or other manipulations to create the overall type.

[image]

The benefit of using 3D here is that you can rotate and adjust the 3D object to create unique curve angles without much trouble. There's obviously some further hand manipulation in you sample. However, this should provide a solid, consistent, base for adding cross bars and end caps manually.

If you want more of a "wrap" to the curves, play with rotating and scaling the **Map Artwork** in the 3D effect. It takes some adjustment to get things to align properly, but it can be worth it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the designer made this with shapes and not some type of wrap text tool. You can achieve something similar by creating circle objects and using pathfinder options to cut the shapes.

Here is an example of how he might have made the h on the bottom right.

Start with 2 circles. Make them elongated. I added stroke so you can see the 2 shapes.

[image: 2 circles over eachother]

use pathfinder minus front to show an eclipse. Make a square shape to cut the eclipse in half.

[image: half eclipse]

I basically then copied that and moved it above the first one and then reversed another eclipse with the transform tool and put it behind the other objects.

Result

[image: result]

This is actually a really cool design. I am sure he did a free hand sketch of how he wanted it to look before hand. You can use the type on path for the other text that is on the inside.

Comment: Thank your for the insight. That is a great approach tackling something like this!